# java.lang.NullPointerException for a data that already exists in Firebase database and I am trying to retrieve it

Tags: java, android, pointers, exception, null

I am creating a small online game, it has 4 principal activities:

An activity for players who host the game and another one for players who will join them.

When a player joins, the Host Activity creates a child called "Matches" in Firebase Database and enters the game details inside it, then it sends the host to a new activity called "OnlineGameForHost" and the joining player to a new Activity called "OnlineGame". This activity tries then to retrieve data from the child "Matches" in the Database but I get that error of: NullPointerException.

I even tried to add a 3 seconds delay before launching "OnlineGame" Activity to make sure data is already on Firebase but still nothing worked.
However I am able to retrieve data instantly when the other Activity "OnlineGameForHost" is launched.. That's quite weird

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>                         at premiereapplication.automation.test.goldsilver_f.OnlineGame$3.onDataChange(OnlineGame.java:171)

```
mUsersDatabase.child("Matches").child(WhenJoining.need+","+mCurrentUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if  (dataSnapshot.child(WhenJoining.need).child("ready").getValue().toString().equals("yes") && dataSnapshot.child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child("ready").getValue().toString().equals("yes"))
            {


            }
```

PS: Line 171 is the "if" statement and just to mention that all the child names are correct as I checked all of them by using Toasts.

Hope to find some solutions and thank you! :)

Comment: the flow looks wrong here... (whenjoining.need).child().... you have a child called whenjoining.need?

Comment: yes all child names are correct, I checked all of them and they are the same as on my database

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing a variable, which can potentially be null, you should always prefer to do the comparison like this,

```
"yes".equals(varname)
```

instead of,

```
varname.equals("yes")
```

This would at least avoid your NullPointerException in case varname is null, while keeping the logic exactly same.

In your given code snippet, looks like this,

```
dataSnapshot.child(WhenJoining.need).child("ready").getValue()
```

is null and calling toString() method is giving you the error you have posted in your question. You can do something like this in your code to avoid it,

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // instead of Object o = ... you can declare the exact class that is returned
    Object o1 = dataSnapshot.child(WhenJoining.need).child("ready").getValue();
    Object o2 = dataSnapshot.child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child("ready").getValue();
    if  ((o1 != null && "yes".equals(o1.toString())) && (o2 != null && "yes".equals(o2.toString())))
    {
    // your code here

    }
```

Comment: I tried to debug: 
mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mUsersDatabase2= mUsersDatabase.child("Matches");
I am getting Null on mUsersDatabase2, although I am looking at my Database at the same time and child "Matches" exists there

Comment: @hamma: I've updated answer with code which should get rid of your NullPointerException. Let me know if you further face any issues.

Comment: I am not getting the NullPointerException anymore but the "if" condition isn't satisfied because o1 and o2 are returning Null. The problem is that FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches") is returning Null although child "Matches" is there